# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in mozilla firefox while using fetch()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I am trying to get data from an API and show it in my browser. I am using the `fetch()` method instead of making an AJAX call. My code is working perfectly in Chrome. However, in Mozilla it's showing this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://starlord.hackerearth.com/movieslisting.
>   (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match
>   ‘http://localhost:8000, *’).

I am using localhost server to run this code and this command to run the server:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Here is my code in vanilla JS :

```
 window.addEventListener("load", getdata, false);
function getdata() {

    fetch("http://starlord.hackerearth.com/movieslisting", {mode: 'cors'})
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            let output = "";
            data.forEach(function (movie) {
                output +=
                    `

            <div class="card shadow-sm border-0">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">${movie.movie_title}</h5>
                    <p>Directed by: ${movie.director_name}</p>
                    <p>Starring: ${movie.actor_1_name} , ${movie.actor_2_name}</p>

                </div>

             </div>
            `;
            });

            document.getElementById('display-listing').innerHTML= output;

        })

}
```

I followed the following link for help. But didn't get any clue:

```
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch
```

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
Request headers :

```
    Origin: http://localhost:8000
Referer: http://localhost:8000/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
```

Response Headers :

```
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 253880
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 08 Sep 2018 17:18:16 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Origin
```

General:

```
  Request URL: http://starlord.hackerearth.com/movieslisting
    Request Method: GET
    Status Code: 200 OK
    Remote Address: 54.179.4.248:80
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Comment: Change mode to 'no-cors'

Comment: In "no-cors" mode you would not be able to access & modify the response data.

Comment: no-cors doesnot work

Comment: please open Developer Tools at Network tab and copy from Request and from Response sections values for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. I'm not sure that I got it clear from your question now. I believe there is no need to change anything on JS side, it's just BE configuration issue

Comment: @skyboyer check my update. Is it what you wanted?

Comment: I don't think this should work on Chrome either (unless you used its settings to make it ignore the SOP)

Comment: is not it strange there are no Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers at all? you are requesting `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` that is definitely not localhost. So there should be CORS headers. Maybe you looking at different request.

Comment: on the other side request to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com looks to be simple(GET request without authorization info or custom headers) so there should be no CORS at all. by the way error message refers to 'http://starlord.hackerearth.com/movieslisting'. Is it related to you project at all? console may display errors for browser's extensions you don't control at all...

Comment: @skyboyer my mistake i copied wrong response. check the edit again

Comment: are you sure it exactly that response that fails? it definitely should work. and again what is a relationship between  'http://starlord.hackerearth.com/movieslisting',  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' and 'localhost:8000'? Currently it looks like you are requesting one resource, getting error about URL on different domain and this is while running additionaly BE on localhost.

Comment: @skyboyer I think I mixed up the question let me update it again

Comment: @skyboyer check the question now

Comment: Check out this snippet to see if it helps:
https://gist.github.com/khalidx/6d6ebcd66b6775dae41477cffaa601e5

Comment: @streletss Can't it be done in codes?

Comment: Client side? No, it must be handled on the server.

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue after latest FF update. Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://dev.oplachu.com/api/v4/app_properties/user_agreement. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://localhost:3000, *’). Server response is Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
http://localhost:3000. Why does it want ‘http://localhost:3000, *’? It's ok in Chrome.

Comment: @AlexKumundzhiev Ya its a problem I am facing only in mozilla

Comment: @UdG only in mozilla and only in linux build. I've tried latest 62.0 windows build, it's ok.

Comment: have you tried to disable any kind of adblock?